# browsing via remote access to my PC with TeamViewer. Can sites track my original IP?

Tags: vpn, security

I have a PC connected to the internet with IP#1. I remotely access it to connect to websites from my other PC IP#2 via teamviewer. obviously sites can see IP#1 but is it possible for them to track the original IP I am using to control the PC remotely IP#2?

Would using VPN/Proxy before remotely connecting to the PC which is doing the browsing do anything to mask my original IP (IP#2)?

Thanks,

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using TeamViewer should obscure IP#2 as long as nobody is watching the traffic in and out of IP#1. Any website that is browsed should only see traffic originating from IP#1.